# Why this django form not pass value back using initial argrument from view.py?

Tags: django

I have a form:

```
class ConfigNotifyForm(forms.Form):
    sensor_name = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),
                        label="Sensor", 
                        choices=[],
                        required=True)
    value_min = forms.FloatField(label="Value Min", required=True)
    value_max = forms.FloatField(label="Value Max", required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConfigNotifyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Get 'initial' argument if any
        initial_arguments = kwargs.get('initial', None)
        sensor_choices = ''
        if initial_arguments != None:
            #for choice in initial_arguments.get('src_choices'):
            sensor_choices = tuple(initial_arguments.get('src_choices'))

        self.fields['sensor_name'].choices = sensor_choices
```

It's work ok with template. But when submit, sensor_name not in cleandata except value_min, and value_max. So, it not pass form.is_valid.

But, if I code **init** like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ConfigNotifyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    sensor_choices = (
        ('', 'Select'), 
        ('a0', 'Ndo'), 
        ('a1', 'pH'), 
        ('a2', 'DO'))
    self.fields['sensor_name'].choices = sensor_choices
```

It's OK. Form is valid. I don't know why. Can anyone help me explain and resolve this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your form `ConfigNotifyForm` you have mentioned `sensor_name` as `required=True`. This means that this field cannot be nothing. You HAVE TO pass a value to it in order for your form to be valid. When in your `__init__` you hardcode the choices, the field is no more nothing/empty and hence it becomes valid.

Comment: So src_choices should be a required argument in ‘__init__’

Comment: If your system does not require `sensor_name`, then remove `required=True` from the form. Else make sure that the form always gets some value in sensor_name. You could do this by providing some default choice instead of an empty list.

Comment: @unixia yes I had try required=False but it not resolve problem. I sure all value are ok when submit because I can get it all by using request.POST.